# Cargar link en un iframe al dar click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quiero que al dar click en la etiqueta **a** el link pase al iframe y se cargue

```
<a href="https://www.google.com">Cargar</a>

<iframe id="container" src=""></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tambien puedes resolverlo sin javascript

```html
<iframe src="pagina.html" name="iframe_a"></iframe>
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com" target="iframe_a">W3Schools.com</a>
```

Solo tienes que ponerle un "name" al iframe  y poner el nombre del name dentro del target del link.

Puedes revisar mas sobre esto en:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe_target

Answer (score 2):

espero que esto te sirva.

Se me ocurren muchas maneras de hacerlo, pero te dejo una sencilla, que es utilizando JavaScript.

Solo te recomiendo que leas sobre X-Frame-Options, porque hay algunas limitaciones con iframe.

Puedes leer más aquí https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

```
<a href="#" onclick="changeURL()" >Cargar</a>

  <iframe id="container" src=""></iframe>

  <script>
      function changeURL() {
            var ifr = document.getElementById("container");
            ifr.setAttribute("src", "https://www.iqstudiogt.com");          
      }
  </script>
```